# Check if CI query has results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the below function inside the useraccount model

```
public function verification_status($balpaycustid){
    $result = $this->db->where('active',1)->where('locked',0)->where('balpaycustid',$balpaycustid)->get('useraccount')->row();
    return $result;
}
```

This returns the below object (if there is a result)

```
stdClass Object
(
  [id] => 3
  [verified] => 
  [active] => 1
  [locked] => 0
  [account] => 123456790
)
```

I'd prefer if this function would return `FALSE` if there were no results, though I'm not entire sure how to do that. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it somewhat bloats your method a bit, you could use `num_rows` to check that there are results before doing your return.

Something along the lines of:

```
public function verification_status($balpaycustid){

    $result = $this->db->where('active',1)->where('locked',0)->where('balpaycustid',$balpaycustid)->get('useraccount');

    if ($result->num_rows()) {
        return $result->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: ah cool. I was hoping for something like that. That will work perfectly. On a side note, am I able to condense my multiple `wheres`?

Comment: yep, you can send it an array, e.g., `$wheres = array('active'=>1,'locked'=>0); $this->db->where($wheres)` etc

Answer (score 2):

Try this , using `num_rows()` to count how many records you have

```
public function verification_status($balpaycustid){
    $result = $this->db->where('active',1)->where('locked',0)->where('balpaycustid',$balpaycustid)->get('useraccount')->row();

    return ($result->num_rows() > 0)? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improvements to implement:

1. This can be written as a returned one-liner, but the line becomes a bit too long.  I would probably declare an array of WHERE conditions to keep the code to a reasonable width.
2. `get_where()` will accept the table name as the first parameter then your associative array of WHERE clause conditions as the second parameter in a single, tidy method call.
3. `row()` will return a populated object or `null`.
4. Since you wish to `return false` when no object is generated, just use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) (available since PHP7.0) to concisely execute this conversion.
5. **Effectively, there is no reason to make the extra call of `num_rows()`.**

Suggested snippet:

```
public function verification_status($balpaycustid) {
    $conditions = ['active' => 1, 'locked' => 0, 'balpaycustid' => $balpaycustid];
    return $this->db->get_where('useraccount', $conditions)->row() ?? false;
}
```